# Battery indicator ALWAYS says Using Battery Power - even when plugged in

Tags: 14.04, asus, battery

I have an ASUS N550JK laptop (BIOS version 204) running Ubuntu 14.04 (3.13.0-43-generic kernel).

My issue is that the battery indicator ALWAYS shows that it's using battery power - even when plugged in and fully charged. So even though I have selected to show the battery status in the menu bar only when charging or in use (in power settings), it is ALWAYS displayed. When it reaches a full charge, the indicator icon will either show just the percentage (usually 99% or 100%), or sometimes a very big number for time (like 22:14) along with the percentage. If I go to the power settings menu, it always says "Using battery power", with something like 40 hours remaining. This is all while plugged in and fully charged.

Are there any fixes less drastic than trying to update BIOS, or is a BIOS update necessary to fix this? The latest BIOS version is 208 according to the ASUS website, but the (very brief) descriptions of the updates don't mention anything about battery issues. If at all possible I'd like to avoid updating BIOS because of the risk involved.

I've already tried letting the battery drain all the way and then charging to full, with no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In nine years of using many versions of Ubuntu on probably well over 50 laptops total (long story) I've found this to sometimes occur on new installations but ordinarily it settles down after a few updates.  How long have you had this installation installed?

If you answer less than 2 weeks, please try this.  Press your windows key.  type upd -enter-.  At the update screen PRESS CHECK.  Check will verify if there is anything in need of updating.  After an update your problem (and others you might be unaware of yet) may subside.

Comment: Though it is a new instllation, I've definitely already done a package update.

Comment: As with windows, there are times when updates must be repeated before all are configured correctly.  If you say it is a new installation and you are having such a problem, I would advise you to open the updater and press check.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but as I said above, my system is already completely up to date.

Comment: Having had to update my own system three times in a day, sometimes less than an hour apart, I never take that as a given.